# How to add a many2one relation to a custom model

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I try to add to an order a new attribute that relates to a custom many2one relation. The goal is to choose for each order one specific contract condition. I would like to manage those contract conditions in the database, so that I can easily manage them.

I sort of got far. I can edit those conditions, assign them and get them properly printed. However, on the sale-order form they get displayed in a weird way. Instead of the descirption-text of the condition, I see sort of a description of the associated record. So my question is, how to show the proper description attribute. See here:

[image: Problem]

Below I added a few screenshots that explain the type of changes that I did.

custom data structure:
[image: custom data structure]

many2one relation from sale.order to custom structure:
[image: many2one relation from sale.order to custom structure]

views for custom structure:
[image: views for custom structure]

reference from order form, which is displayed oddly
[image: reference from order form, which is displayed oddly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define _rec_name into your class.

```
_rec_name = 'x_condition'
```

It's because it will looking for name field into your custom model when you add many2one field for that model, when you define _rec_name it will take that field value.

Comment: So that means that I will have to write a Python Add-on to get this working? I was hoping that I could avoid that, since everything else works just fine.

Comment: It's always advisable to do this kind of things by adding new add-on to kept your changes permanent, changes made from UI will wipes when it's base module updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use x_name instead of x_condition for field name